# Sum of Char value in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to count the different values in one column.  It is Char data type.  I wrote my code in oracle which works but I cannot change the syntax in SQL server;

This works:

```
Select l.name, l.address,
       SUM(DECODE(L.SEX,   'M',   1,   0)) MALE_TOTAL,
       SUM(DECODE(L.SEX,   'F',   1,   0)) FEMALE_TOTAL,
       SUM(DECODE(L.SEX,   'U',   1,   0)) UNKNOWN_TOTAL
From personnel
```

Thanks a bunch

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server?

Comment: What database are you using?  It looks like neither SQL Server nor MySQL.

Comment: he's going for sql server

Comment: I am using SQL Server 12.0.

Comment: I tried IFF - It says not a recognized function.  I tried the case solution , it says column is invalid, it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause.

Comment: IIF not IFF please see solution

Comment: tried also TO_CHAR(Sum(l.sex, 'M', 1,0), no luck

Comment: where did you get that?

Comment: I changed it to IIF(bad type sorry)

Comment: still error, it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause...

Comment: I do have group by l.sex not sure why still gives error

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard method for what you want is:

```
Select l.name, l.address,
       SUM(CASE WHEN L.SEX = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MALE_TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN L.SEX = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FEMALE_TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN L.SEX = 'U' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) UNKNOWN_TOTAL
From personnel
group by l.name, l.address;
```

Note the `GROUP BY`.  If you want one row per name/address, then you need this.  Otherwise remove the columns from the `SELECT`:

```
Select SUM(CASE WHEN L.SEX = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MALE_TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN L.SEX = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FEMALE_TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN L.SEX = 'U' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) UNKNOWN_TOTAL
From personnel;
```

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use IIF 2012 +

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql

```
SELECT
  SUM(IIF(L.SEX = 'M', 1, 0)) MALE_TOTAL,
  SUM(IIF(L.SEX = 'F', 1, 0)) FEMALE_TOTAL,
  SUM(IIF(L.SEX = 'U', 1, 0)) UNKNOWN_TOTAL
FROM personnel
```

OR CASE

```
SELECT
  SUM(case when L.SEX = 'M' then 1 else 0 end)) MALE_TOTAL,
  SUM(case when L.SEX = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) FEMALE_TOTAL,
  SUM(case when L.SEX = 'U' then 1 else 0 end) UNKNOWN_TOTAL
FROM personnel
```

Comment: Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!